# numpy column wise division to the power of n

Tags: python, numpy, operations

I have a pandas dataframe in python and I want to generate RevenueCAGR column,

```
Company Name                zumba pty ltd
Total Revenue;2018-06-30          17102.2
Total Revenue;2016-06-30           2111.5
RevenueCAGR                   4.22897e+16


x2 = {'Total Revenue;2018-06-30' : [17012.2],
                'Total Revenue;2016-06-30' : [2111.5],
                'RevenueCAGR' : [422897]}

x2df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x2)
```

I am trying to get (Total Revenue;2018-06-30/Total Revenue;2016-06-30)^(1/3)-1.

I tried

```
df['RevenueCAGR'] = np.power(df['Total Revenue;2018-06-30']/df['Total Revenue;2016-06-30'], 1/3) -1
```

And I got this error:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

How do you get column wise operations in python to take to the power of a float?

Comment: I see `(17102.2/2111.5)**(1/3)-1 = 1.00826`, please clarify.

Comment: Perhaps provide example code to reproduce `df` (minimal code).

Comment: @jpp yes, so my current operation for producing RevenueCAGR is wrong...

Comment: @abi guessing you had a typo?

Comment: @DanielF where?

Comment: I don't know, but your code runs fine here, even with the df definition you give.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is structured correctly, your code will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TR_2018': [17102.2],
                   'TR_2016': [2111.5]})

df['RevenueCAGR'] =  np.power(df['TR_2018']/df['TR_2016'], 1/3) -1

print(df)

   TR_2016  TR_2018  RevenueCAGR
0   2111.5  17102.2     1.008262
```